# Replacing Carpet with Hardwood floor - contractor issues on base board cutting

Tags: drywall, hardwood-floor, baseboard

We new to home improvements. We are getting carpet area on upperfloor hallway replaced with hardwood. The contractor cut the baseboard to fit the hardwoods in, on one part we saw 2 hardwoood atleast 3-4 inches extra inside the wall. This wall is just opposite to stairs so we could see it. He says the shoe molding covers it all but I am afraid he damaged our drywall. Is it the common way the hardwood gets installed? or we have been fooled by contractor.

There is broken base board and wall behind this shoe molding. Also having edges of hardwood inside the wall. I am so disheartened. Is there solution to fix this problem? Or leave it alone with shoe molding covering it up?
[image]

Comment: It could be that you have wide floor planks and one strip had to be cut narrower to fill the gap at the wall and this is 100% normal and expected. _However_, without pictures, we can't tell.

Comment: It's trivial to remove that shoe molding, take a picture, and then nail it back into place. You just need some finishing nails.

Comment: That's a great start! So far, I'm not seeing an issue, so a nice close up showing _exactly_ what the problem is would be very helpful. The only thing that catches my eye is that the shoe moulding is wider than the door casing and, on the right-hand door, it looks odd from this angle.

Comment: As @MonkeyZeus suggested, you can pull the shoe molding for a picture. A small pry-bar, a block of wood to put between the pry-bar and the trim (so you're not digging into the trim and damaging it with the pry-bar), and it'll pop right off. Start at the end of the shoe molding and gently work your way along it, prying where the nails are.

Comment: @FreeMan The shoe molding near door casing problem is unfortunately all too common. The installer should have cut the end at an angle so that there is a more seamless transition from baseboard to door casing.

Comment: Even with the photo I'm not sure what's being asked here. 3-4 inches under the wall is almost out the other side of the wall. That doesn't make sense. At any rate, it looks fine to me. What am I missing?

Comment: Regarding bevels at the end of base shoe, there are much better options. Bevels look amateurish, in my opinion, as they don't coordinate with the profile of the molding and exposed end grain should be avoided to begin with. Instead, use a miter return to the [wall](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3c/f1/a6/3cf1a685daccacf7f29d30519de68da7.jpg) or [floor](https://www.laminate-flooring-installed.com/images/12345Quarter_round_Woodgrain_return_BIG.jpg). Return to the wall for new construction, and to the floor when fitting flooring around casing where gaps need coverage.

Comment: Thank you for reply. As circled in picture, that particular part (door casing to door casing) of wall is ruined. I will try to put pictures by removing the molding. The contractor, a reputed company is not taking responsibility of their worker's mistake and getting it fixed. Instead covering with shoe molding even after knowing there is broken wall and 3- 4 inches of hardwood edge inside.

Answer (score 4):

If your baseboard goes down to the subfloor then I would be very surprised that the installer took the time to cut into it so that hardwood would go under it. If the contractor has a specialty tool for this which makes the endeavor take seconds instead of using an oscillating multi-tool then that would be cool.

Anyways, the baseboard was probably cut unevenly so brand new shoe molding is designed explicitly to hide the imperfections where your floor meets the baseboard; regardless of whether the floor goes under the baseboard or butts up right against it.

What exactly is the issue if hidden drywall was damaged a little bit?

In your mind what exactly would make things right or better? Based on your worries "making it right" is going to be expensive.

Overall, the install looks fairly proper. Patch the holes and add a fresh coat of paint on your baseboard and shoe molding and it will look great.